# request addparameter array but return empty in response

Tags: json, serialization, restsharp

I use RestSharp.

I have a list `private List<string> _GuyIds;` Then

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void GuyMetadataServiceShouldReturnExpected()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/OrionServices/GuyService.svc/");

        var request = new RestRequest("{facilityId}/Guys/metadata/", Method.POST);
        request.AddUrlSegment("facilityId", "888");
        request.AddParameter("GuyIds", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_GuyIds.ToArray()), ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
```

In the service,

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/{FacilityID}/Guys/metadata/")]
    public List<dynamic> GenerateMetadata(string FacilityID)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Expires", "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

        var Guys = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(OperationContext.Current.RequestContext
            .RequestMessage.GetBody<byte[]>());
```

When I hover over the `Guys` in the service code, I got

> `["0001","0003","0004","0005","0006"]`

However when I check the response, the content is empty. I guess that something wrong when I passed the array to the request in this line.

```
request.AddParameter("GuyIds", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_GuyIds.ToArray()), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out by myself. WCF doesn't support serializing dynamic type. I have to define a POCO object.

```
   [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/{FacilityID}/Guys/metadata/")]
public List<GuysDTO> GenerateMetadata(string FacilityID)
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Expires", "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Then

```
public class GuyDTO
{
     public string metadata1 {get;set;}
      ....
}
```